# Galaxy trucker gold club struggle

Tags: ios, galaxy-trucker

I’m trying to collect my three recommendations. I’ve gotten the one from the businessman, and one from the scientist. Presumably, the last one is from the instructor, or the Barman. The instructor keeps eating his pizza and says he’s busy. I’ve delivered the barmans drinks, so I’m not sure what to do. Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the game was in a bit of a weird state.
Parts of the game knew I had my class three license and parts didn’t, for example, my instructor.

Comment: And how did you resolve (or discover) this weird state?